# in adminlte template is there a way to expand box in modal or make full screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

i am using bootstrap adminLTE template, is there a way to expand box in modal or make full screen? i want to expand my chart in modal or show in full screen?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working sample code describing your problem and your efforts to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature is not yet supported as of Jan 2016.

https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/865